# Dialog box in Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

Is there a way to display a (preferably modal) dialog box in an servlet controller ?  If it isn't modal that is something I can deal with (!?) as long as it initially appears above the browser.

Essentially I have a form with a table and 2 buttons on it.  One button takes the user to a different place in the workflow and is irrelevant to this question (just to explain why the other one doesn't 'go anywhere').

The other button currently goes back to an MVC controller, calls some code to export the table to excel and then reloads the web page.  This is all working okay except the way I am calling the dialog box is calling it underneath the browser.  I suspect this is because I am sending null as the frame but I'm not sure what to put in its place ?

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Export Completed.", "Excel Export",     JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are doing? `JOptionPane` is a class from Java's Swing toolkit, i.e. a thick client running on the user's PC or at most within a Java Applet.

Comment: No I've jsut switched from Microsoft technologies and am pretty much doing everything for the first time.  That could well be the wrong way to go, I took it from a google search to see if it would work and then posted this question when it didn't!  If there is an alternative I can drop that approach.

Comment: Swing is essentially used to build client applications that run completely on the user's computer, its like when you create a new dialog-based application in Visual Studio. Even in Microsoft technologies, you can't simply create a dialog in that way when dealing with an ASP.NET web-based application. What you need is an HTML/CSS/Javascript based solution, that is what a browser understands irrespective of whether you are using Java, ASP, PHP or whatever. Or you could simply redirect to a page that says "Export to Excel Complete".

Comment: Fair point.  Thanks for that.  I must admit I guessed as much (although I am much more used to forms programming) but I thought it was worth chancing that there was something behind the scenes.  I guess that hope probably came from not  thinking clearly about how the servlets work.  For now I will Just send back an attribute 'exported' so that I can get the page to do the work itself.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer with a few issues to keep in mind when developing these kinds of web apps. See if they apply to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too sure what you are trying to achieve from your question and without any code examples. However, presumably what you are doing (guessing here), is that you are trying to export some data from some data source and convert it to an Excel file. You have to keep 3 things in mind.

1. Web applications work via HTTP requests and responses. So the only thing a Servlet can do is send back an HTTP response that indicates that the export was successful. Whether you use a traditional page, or maybe use AJAX to avoid refreshing the page is purely your design choice. You could also start with a simple page and then change to AJAX combined with JQuery later once you get used to what is happening.
2. Exporting the excel sheet to the server does not mean that your client has access to it. Speculating here, but you will probably need a mechanism for your user to get the file. One simple approach used by many webapps is to actually send the Excel file as the Servlet response itself. So what would happen is that when the export is completed the browser starts receiving the file and the user sees it downloading. From your servlet you will just need to set the right mime-type and set the `content-disposition` header to state that the file is an `attachment` (so that the browser downloads it as a file).

   `httpresp.setContentType("text/csv");`

   `httpresp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"export.csv\"");`

   You will probably also need to set the file size. There are various full examples on SO if you look for further details.
3. When performing these operations remember that users can interrupt the browser or refresh. If the user presses F5 he might cause your application to do the export again. One common approach to this is called 'redirect-after-post'. Basically you redirect the user to a page which just displays the outcome, without performing the operation again. This way if he presses refresh, he is just refreshing the page with the message.